# Get info about installed and remote packages with pacman

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I'm using [`pacman`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/pacman) 5.0.1 on Arch Linux and I'd like to get information about packages installed on my machine as well as packages in the remote repositories.

Information should include a description of the package, its size, and its build date.

Comment: I don't get it, you asked this question not even one minute before you answered it yourself. You seem to do that a lot, is that just to increase your reputation artificially?

Comment: @RedGlyph: This site also encourages answering one's own questions, see [this checkbox](https://i.imgur.com/VOSOpO5.png) from the "Answer Question" form. You're right, I've made a habit out of publishing the solutions I found to the questions I had. I do this in order for others to profit from my endeavors and for myself since this documents my solutions. It doesn't increase my reputation artificially, instead, other people vote on my Q&As if they found them useful, that's how reputation is increased.

Comment: That's interesting. That looked a little weird on a question-based site, but why not? Thanks for the info!

Comment: I'm happy to have cleared things up! :-) There's actually a common school of thought behind my way of using Stack Exchange, from the [SO Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour): *... we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming*

Answer (score 63, accepted):

### Using `--info`

Taking [`vi`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) as an example, to get information about its *locally* installed package use

```
pacman -Q --info vi
```

This produces

```
Name            : vi
Version         : 1:070224-2
Description     : The original ex/vi text editor
Architecture    : x86_64
URL             : http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/
Licenses        : custom:ex
Groups          : base
Provides        : None
Depends On      : ncurses
Optional Deps   : s-nail: used by the preserve command for notification [installed]
Required By     : None
Optional For    : None
Conflicts With  : None
Replaces        : None
Installed Size  : 290.00 KiB
Packager        : Evangelos Foutras <evangelos@foutrelis.com>
Build Date      : Sun 06 Sep 2015 09:34:15 PM CEST
Install Date    : Mon 03 Oct 2016 07:18:13 PM CEST
Install Reason  : Explicitly installed
Install Script  : No
Validated By    : Signature
```

Alternatively use the shorter `-i` option:

```
pacman -Qi vi
```

To only get the value of a **specific** package property, let's say the description, there's good old [`grep`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) to filter the output:

```
pacman -Qi vi | grep -Po '^Description\s*: \K.+'
```

Which prints

> The original ex/vi text editor

A short explanation of the `grep` command above:

- `-P` activates Perl-compatible regular expressions
- `-o` print only the matched parts of a matching line, not the whole line
- `^Description\s*: \K.+` is the regex: The line must start with "Description" followed by any number of whitespace characters, followed by ": ". Then:

  - `\K` resets the starting point of the match. The matched characters starting with "Description" are not included in the final match
  - Finally, `.+` matches everything afterwards, which is the package description

Here's a general [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673287/how-to-remove-a-word-prefix-using-grep/56236273#56236273) on how to remove known prefixes from lines.

---

Getting information from the *remote* repository works similar:

```
pacman -Si vi
```

When you only know parts of the package's name, use the `-s` option:

```
pacman -Ss jdk
```

---

To find out which packages depend on a certain package — for example if you're wondering why a package exists on your system — you can use [pactree](https://man.archlinux.org/man/pactree.8):

```
pactree -r intel-media-driver
```

which produces a nice dependency tree:

```
intel-media-driver
└─intel-media-sdk
  └─ffmpeg
    ├─electron6
    │ └─code
    ├─firefox
    ├─freerdp
    │ └─wlroots
    │   └─sway
    ├─qt5-webengine
    │ └─python2-pyqtwebengine
    │   └─calibre
    ├─unpaper
    │ └─ocrmypdf
    ├─vlc
    └─wf-recorder-git
```

### Minimal package browser

Combining the previous commands with [fzf](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Fzf) allows for a minimal textual package browser.

For local packages:

```
cmd='(pacman -Qi {}; pactree -r {})'; pacman -Q --quiet | fzf --preview "$cmd"
```

For remote packages:

```
cmd='pacman -Si {2}'; pacman -S --list | fzf --preview "$cmd"
```

You can scroll the preview with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>.

To open the preview in your editor with <kbd>Enter</kbd>, change the command to:

```
fzf --preview "$cmd" --bind "enter:execute($EDITOR <($cmd))"
```

Here the contents of the preview are passed to your editor using [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).